# Linked external framework - but it doesn't show up in the Frameworks folder

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I'm adding an external framework to my project. I added it by adding the framework to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.

[image]

However, libMSODataLib.a is not showing up under my Frameworks folder.

[image]

**Should I be concerned?** Am I adding the framework incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely at the top of your project file list. You can drag & drop from the top of the list to your Frameworks folder but your Link with Libraries section will show it as "missing". To alleviate THAT issue drag from the frameworks folder back over to your Link with Libraries folder and it will toggle back from red (missing) to black (ok).

EDIT:
This won't negatively affect your project but will it will drive you nuts if you're OCD with your project files ;)